# .NET widget to convert RTF to HTML

Tags: .net

I want a .NET widget that can convert RTF to raw HTML and vice-versa. Any suggestions?

**Edited:**

Free Tools only.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

It supports DOC, OOXML, RTF, HTML, OpenDocument, PDF, XPS, EPUB and other formats.

**Edit:**

If you are looking for a free tool then have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150208/how-do-i-convert-html-to-rtf-rich-text-in-net-without-paying-for-a-component) (How do I convert HTML to RTF (Rich Text) in .NET without paying for a component?).

Comment: @RPK - I would suggest you add that to the original question then otherwise people will make the same mistake

Comment: @Robert: Added. Commercial will also do bust Aspose is quite expensive.