# Editing HTML with a WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: c#, html, string, datagridview, wysiwyg

I have a datagridview with HTML strings. Using a CellDoubleClick event, I am displaying the html string in a WebBrowser control.

**In Form1**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            string s = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            this.f2 = new Form2(s);
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

**In Form2**

```
private IHTMLDocument2 doc;
string reply;

public Form2(string reply)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.reply = reply;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = reply; <--- string from DataGridView

    IHTMLTxtRange range = doc.selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
    range.pasteHTML(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();

    doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    doc.designMode = "On";
}
```

Using the above code, I can successfully display the HTML string as a plaintext, however I am unable to edit it. Alternatively, if I use this code:

```
private IHTMLDocument2 doc;
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = reply; <--- string from DataGridView

    doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    doc.designMode = "On";

    IHTMLTxtRange range = doc.selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
    range.pasteHTML(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
}
```

It will be a blank form, but I will be able to write to it.

I have a feeling it has to do with `range.pasteHTML(webBrowser1.DocumentText);` being in the Form2_Load method, but I'm unaware of any other method that will allow me to display the HTML string from the DataGridView upon opening Form2.

I want to allow users to be able to edit the HTML string as plaintext (after which it will be converted back to HTML and displayed in the datagridview).

Answer (score 1):

**Its possible!** You can edit HTML using the default `WebBrowser` control,

1. Add a reference to the "Microsoft.mshtml.dll" file, available here.
2. Assuming your WebBrowser is named "browser", add this code in the Form.Load event
   `(browser.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).designMode = "On";`
3. Call the following functions to format the selected text:

---

```
browser.document.ExecCommand("Bold", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("Underline", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("Italics", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("StrikeThrough", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontName", false, "Times New Roman");
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontName", false, "Arial");
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontName", false, "etc.");
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontSize", false, "1");
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontSize", false, "2");
browser.document.ExecCommand("FontSize", false, "3");
browser.document.ExecCommand("InsertUnorderedList", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("InsertOrderedList", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("Cut", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("Paste", false, null);
browser.document.ExecCommand("CreateLink", true, null);
```

---

<strike>The `WebBrowser` control does not allow editing, and is designed to view web pages only. Its actually the Internet Explorer/Trident rendering engine operating behind the scenes that parses the HTML and renders the final page complete with DOM/JS support. No popular browser supports editing of HTML pages, IMO, and neither does IE.</strike>