# How to make certain text in a TextBrick bold

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have used textbrick to display my Text. I want to show certain part of the text bold. Is that possible?

For example:

```
TextBrick tb = new TextBrick();
tb.Rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, e.Graph.ClientPageSize.Width, 100);
tb.Text="Profile Name : "+lblProfile.Text;
```

I want to make 'Profile Name' bold.

Comment: No it is not possible. you can use multiple `TextBrick` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You simply set Font property

```
tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the [RichTextBrick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#corelibraries/clsDevExpressXtraPrintingRichTextBricktopic) instead of the TextBrick. Note that you need to provide RTF formated text. One of the approaches discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922626/c-sharp-net-converting-html-to-rtf)