# How to parse HTML to Text with styles

Tags: c#, html, xamarin.android

I'm building an app using Xamarin Android, and I want to convert HTML to normal with formatting, for example :

> HTML Code

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> is placeholder text <strong><em><span style="color:#ff0000">commonly</span></em></strong> used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

> Text

**Lorem ipsum** is placeholder text ***commonly*** used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

I get this content from the database and I want to convert ***post*** content to Text with formatting.

Comment: Define normal text, there is nothing normal about your normal text example

Comment: ok, thanks for the help I edited.

Comment: Try to convert html to rtf.
See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922626/c-sharp-net-converting-html-to-rtf

Comment: @JuarezJúnior that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The TextView currently supports the following HTML tags as listed [in this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html):

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

If you just want to display it in a TextView then simply do something like this:

```
TextView txtView;
txtView.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(HTMLFromDataSource);
```

If you want to use a different control then there are other ways to achieve this, but the TextView supports HTML to a degree anyway so if you can use that, I would.

However it is worth noting that UL and LI doesn't look to currently be supported. So you would have to use something like the `Html.TagHandler` to tell it what to do, here is a Java implementation:

```
public class UlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                          XMLReader xmlReader) {
            if(tag.equals("ul") && !opening) output.append("\n");
            if(tag.equals("li") && opening) output.append("\n\t•");
    }
}

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText, null, new UlTagHandler()));
```

You should be able to convert that to C# for Xamarin.

Comment: I appreciate it, that could help.