# Is it possible to convert HTML to Richtext format?

Tags: asp.net, freetext

I have a `freetextbox` and want to convert it's output to `richtext` format.
for example this is the text of my freetext:

```
<b>loblob</b>
```

how to convert it to Richtext format?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, this has been asked before:
[HTML to RTF Converter for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042843/html-to-rtf-converter-for-net)

And there is very basic example in CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11252/Gios-WORD-NET-Library-using-RTF-specification

You will need to work a bit though, its not that easy