# Convert RTF to HTML in .NET

Tags: .net, html, rtf

I've managed to do the reverse using `WebBrowser` and `RichTextBox`.

But how would I convert RTF to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm working for this company.

As I see, the question is old but maybe someone search solution for this too. Our component RTF to HTML allows to convert RTF to HTML. You may download a component or try online-demo. Try the trial version first if you have a doubt. :) Trial is free.

Here's the code sample for the converting from RTF to HTML in ASP.NET:

```
    SautinSoft.RtfToHtml r = new SautinSoft.RtfToHtml();
    r.OutputFormat = SautinSoft.RtfToHtml.eOutputFormat.HTML_401;
    r.ImageStyle.IncludeImageInHtml = false; //To save images inside HTML as binary data specify this property to 'true'

    r.ImageStyle.ImageFolder = Server.MapPath(""); 
    r.ImageStyle.ImageSubFolder = "images";
    r.ImageStyle.ImageFileName = "picture";       

    string rtf = ".....";
    string html = r.ConvertString(rtf);        

    //show HTML
    if (html.Length>0)
    {
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        Response.Write(html);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I converted rtf to html successfully using your code but when I loaded that html contents in TinyMCE editor and updated them, it saves only plane text. It looses its style. Please help.

Comment: Actually @BrainSlugs83 answer should be accepted one since this answer promotes paid tool while solution that BrainSlugs83 has provided is free and it works.

Answer (score 16):

If you pop-up NuGet and search for "RTF", the most popular result right now looks like `RtfPipe`; you can install it right there, or via the package manager console via:

```
Install-Package RtfPipe
```

Then in your C#, you can convert RTF to HTML super easily:

```
var html = RtfPipe.Rtf.ToHtml(rtf);
```

According to the readme.md on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe):

> This library attempts to support the core RTF features documented in the RTF Specification 1.9.1. These features include:
>
> - Character formatting (bold, italics, color, ...)
> - Tables (including nested tables)
> - Lists
> - Hyperlinks
> - Pictures
> - Heading levels
> - HTML encapsulation (e.g. as performed by Outlook)
>
> With that said, there are numerous cases for non-trivial documents where the library will not produce the "correct" visual representation when compared to other RTF readers (such as MS Word).

I piped my RTF into it, and it worked amazingly. YYMV.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is when you work on a budget, additional costs mean lower profit, so I started to develop my own version.  The main problem is that at the moment it only supports **Bold** and *Italic*, and certain entities (&amp, &copy, &reg, &trade, &euro and &###) and lacks both font and color support, but it is still a work in progress.  I am adding font and color, but my headache is that these could come from stylesheets rather than the old fashion html tags.

I am writing this in VB.NET and have posted the startup code on CodeProject

[Startup Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1011178/RTF-to-HTML-VB-Net)

Comment: Rather than just the blurb can  you add enough details of the usage synopsis to your answer so that someone can pick it up right away and understand it?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it programattically you should parse your rtf (is a simple text based file), convert rtf control words to html tags.

Here you can find the rtf specs
http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

or use an already existing converter: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2html-lite/

Comment: Its not straight forward converting tags yourself. No idea how to get a C++ Library into .NET. (its not a DLL)