# How can I get RTF from HTML with CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, rtf

I have a pretty good structure for multiple CKEditor textareas, and when clicking a <kbd>submit</kbd> button I'm letting the user copy/paste the HTML from a JavaScript `prompt`.

However, I want RTF instead of HTML. Do I need another JavaScript plugin, or can this be done with CKEditor?

---

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CKEditor Test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
                .container {
                        margin-left: 30%;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
            <form>
                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="ckeditor1">
                </textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>

            <form>
                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="ckeditor2">
                </textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>

            <form>
                <textarea class="ckeditor" name="ckeditor3">
                </textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
    </div>
    <script src="ckeditor_4.4.4_basic\ckeditor\ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".ckeditor").each(function() {
            CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr("name"));
            CKEDITOR.config.width = 500;
        });

        $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var textarea = $(this).find("textarea:first");
            var name = $(textarea).attr("name");

            // forcing the textarea to update:
            CKEDITOR.instances[name].updateElement();

            var text = textarea.html();
            window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

...what it looks like:
[image: multiple textareas with CKEditor]

...and some sample HTML output (*from the text in the above screenshot*):

```
&lt;p&gt;some top-level text&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;a sub-item&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;another sub-item&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

---

*Note: I'm using [the basic version of CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download), and have disabled some buttons with this line in* `config.js`:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript,Link,Unlink,About';
```

Comment: CKEditor is an HTML editor, not a RTF one. you won't find much in the way of RTF tools on the web; there's really no point of it anymore...

Comment: @dandavis -- ok thanks, except that I need to format HTML into RTF, so that I can later generate this input into a Word document.

Comment: little known trick: if you save an html document as "something.doc", it will open in word just fine. you can also save bare table html as "ss1.xls" to open it in excel just fine.

Comment: @dandavis -- Interesting, didn't know you could do that! However, I will be sending the input to the server, inserting it into the database, and generating a Word document with this and other info with Telerik Standalone Report Designer... so it will be mashed with other data. Maybe there's a C# and/or Telerik solution though, but JavaScript would be preferable.

Comment: So, as an update I now have the HTML from the database correctly displaying through a Telerik HtmlTextBox control, but am still curious if there is a pure JavaScript or C# solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with CKEditor. The idea is to convert the HTML, generated by CKEditor to RTF after editing. A soultion for that can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/155112/4776207.

There are two downsides, I admit, but it could still be a perfectly sufficient solution in your case.

1. The solution is in C# **but** the conversion to JS is rather trivial even without C# knowledge if you guess that 

   `result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
          @"<( )*br( )*>", "\r",
          System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

   converts to

   `result = result.replace(/<( )*br( )*>/gi, "\r");`

   So it should take just a couple of minutes to get the function converted to JS.
2. Regex, may not be a suitable tool for dealing with HTML, ok, **but** for your use case, that needs to be able to deal with a very limited set of html tags, it is powerful enough. You could even leave away much of the conversion function.