# ReferenceError: WebBrowser is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, rtf

I am trying the most upvoted solution for [html to rtf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150208/how-do-i-convert-html-to-rtf-rich-text-in-net-without-paying-for-a-component)

that is by using the browser.

But even the simple start (everything stripped away)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webBrowser = new WebBrowser(); 
</script>
```

gives:
ReferenceError: WebBrowser is not defined

What am I missing?

Comment: I would read the most up-voted solution again. You are trying to execute in JavaScript what they have done in .NET...

Comment: @IanBrindley Well, it *is* JavaScript but it relies on a library provided by .NET. But yes, not being in a .NET environment is the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they are talking about a [.NET class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) in that post, not vanilla JavaScript.

If you need browser info you can use [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.navigator)

If you want to convert RTF to HTML you have to use a cross-browser WYSIWYG editor, such as CkEditor or openWYSIWYG